# PHP cURL - How to upload folders?

Tags: php, curl

I have a simple PHP script that scans an entire directory and uploads all files. But I want it to upload the folders aswell. (and keep the folder structure) How do I do that?

**My code:**

```
$dir = 'Test/';

$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);

$ch = curl_init('https://website.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://website.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

    echo $filename;
    $cFile = curl_file_create($filename);
    $post = array('file'=> $cFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload just a directory, because it is not an information type that you can upload anywhere. However, there are few simplest approaches.

**Approach 1**

> Send a directory name via cURL. For example:
>
> ```
> $post = array('dir'=> $someDirectoryName);
> ```
>
> On the other side just create a directory using PHP function
> [mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)
>
> Remember to pass a path with your file to preserve the directory
> structure:
>
> ```
> $post = array('file'=> $cFile, 'path' => $somePath);
> ```

**Approach 2**

> Just pass a file path with your file data:
>
> ```
> $post = array('file'=> $cFile, 'path' => 'dir1/subdir2/filename.ext');
> ```
>
> On the other side parse 'path' and create all required directories.

**Approach 3**

> Create an archive of your directory (for example, tar.gz) and
> upload that archive. On the other side just unpack the archive to the
> target directory.